# is there an option to repeat export?

Tags: export

I am working with unity and I am constantly exporting fbx files. I wonder if there is a shortcut to repeat the export operation? same filename, same settings, same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **script** for the export. Or command in **Python Console**

The standard fbx_exporter is [`bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx):

A quick example:`bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath='C:/tmp/test.fbx')` (the directory should exist!!)
[image]

For more option you want, see the documentation and change the default value to what you want. And short cut, is some what more complicated. Use <kbd>Alt+P</kbd> in text editor will be lot of easier.